# android notify User on when his data changes in the server

Tags: android

We are working on app which is for fixing their appointment with a doctor. We will have to notify the user on that date by saying if the doctor is available or not.

How can we notify the user when the data changes in the server?

Answer (score 0):

The usual workflow for sending push messages from your server to the application, is the **Google Cloud Messaging**, or the so-called **Push Notification in Android**.
Simply put, you send your message to the Google and the Google will notify your application. The actual heavily lifting is done by the **Google Play Services** Library and its corresponding application, which is installed on every android device. For more information on how to implement it, you may refer to the following links.
[Official Documentation on Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)
[Android Push Notification Tutorial](http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139)

Answer (score 0):

I used [http://pusher.com/ "Pusher"](http://pusher.com/) for a doc app a couple years ago.  It was easy to do and light weight.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I would believe is through a polling technique. However, it would not work for real time updates as there is an update interval. Depending on your application's requirements, this might work!

**In order to do that.**

- You would have to publish a web service which would provide a Unix
  timestamp. e.g. https://Your-base-url/status.aspx
- Each time there is any change on the server, you change the value to a new one on the server.
- Your Android device will poll that web service(status) each say 60 seconds
  to see if there is an update.
- The device would save the timestamp in his device and would check
  whether the two timestamps match.
- If not, then he will call the relevant web services to get updated
  data.

  However, you should note that the Android device will only get to know whenever it polls. So, the device might not know the update until his next polling cycle.

The most accurate way is to maintain a **persistent** Socket connection with your server at all times. Whenever an update occurs, you can immediately send the updates to the device via the open socket. However, this is more complicated as you will have to deal with the socket connections.

GCM uses socket connections internally. Therefore, a solution including GCM is an easier approach.